# Different behaviors with const modifier in JsonArray and Array APIs

Tags: windows, uwp, c++-cx

I am doing some C++/CX development. I am having different behavior using two different APIs of arrays. The const modifier in the Platform::Array allows me to access the Length property getter, but in the Windows::Data::Json::JsonArray the Size property getter cannot be accessed under the same circumstances. Is there a concrete reason why different APIs of Microsoft have different behavior for the const modifier?

Comment: I posted some basic info but if you show your actual code, I might be able to add something more helpful

Comment: I think I'm good with the information you gave. Your answer makes perfect sense to me since I had no idea Windows.* was direct WinRT call instead of a C++ bridge to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Platform::Array` is a C++/CX type and can use C++ features (like `const`). `Windows::Data::Json::JsonArray` is a WinRT type and can only use WinRT features, and there is no `const` feature in WinRT (because not all languages support it).